# Check a record exists already and stop the loop in a recursive query

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a SQLite table saving class inherit information, I need to get all ascendant classes or descendant classes in the inherit chain. I use recursive query to get these two fields of all classes for the target class.

DB table: Classes, with field uuid (class name as string) and parentClass (parent class name as string).

For instance I want to get all descendant classes for class "A", this is my code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS( 
    SELECT uuid, parentClass FROM Classes 
    WHERE uuid = 'A' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c.uuid, c.parentClass FROM Classes c, CTE p 
    WHERE c.parentClass=p.uuid 
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Problem is that I have no guarantee that there is no loop inherit by mistake, which will freeze my program. I want to use "NOT EXISTS" statement to stop when I found loop (uuid exists already in the CTE) but error "multiple reference to CTE" raises. Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UNION instead of UNION ALL to detect recursion loops.
From sqlite [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

> If a UNION operator connects the initial-select with the recursive-select, then only add rows to the queue if no identical row has been previously added to the queue. Repeated rows are discarded before being added to the queue even if the repeated rows have already been extracted from the queue by the recursion step. If the operator is UNION ALL, then all rows generated by both the initial-select and the recursive-select are always added to the queue even if they are repeats.